# IndexError: list index out of range on a walking character

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to make a character to move, but when I walk a certain distance, it gets an error

I can't find a viable solution so I just tried a few things by myself

```py
global walkCount
win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
    walkCount = 0
if left:
    win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x, y))
    walkCount += 1
    pygame.display.update()
elif right:
      win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x,y))
      walkCount += 1
      pygame.display.update()
```

> ```
> File "C:\Users\drfur\Desktop\Game\game.py", line 166, in <module>
>    rwg()
>
> File "C:\Users\drfur\Desktop\Game\game.py", line 55, in rwg
>    win.blit(walkRight[walkcount//3], (x,y))
>
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

it happens on either left and right

Comment: What are `walkRight` and `walkLeft`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum of `walkCount` is 26. The result of `26//3` is 8. You've to ensure that the lists `walkLeft` and `walkRight` have 9 elements.

The list index out of range error can be avoided by calculating the reminder of a division by the length of the list. The remainder can be calculated by the modulo operator (`%`). See [Operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions). e.g.:

```py
if left:

    i = (walkCount//3) % len(walkLeft)
    win.blit(walkLeft[i], (x, y))

elif right:

    i = (walkCount//3) % len(walkRight)
    win.blit(walkRight[i], (x,y))

walkCount += 1
pygame.display.update()
```